# Sum of multinomals = sum of binomials: why?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

I stumbled on the following identity, which has been checked numerically.

> **Question.** Is this true? If so, any proof?
>   $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k}2\rfloor}\binom{n-2k+j}{j,k-2j,n-3k+2j}
> =\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{k}2\rfloor}\binom{n-k-2j-1}{k-2j}.$$

Here, $\binom{m}{a,b,c}$ is understood as $\frac{m!}{a!\,b!\,c!}$.

Comment: Set $m=n-2k$. Then
$$
  \binom{n-2k+j}{j,k-2j,n-3k+2j} = \binom{k-j}{j}\binom{m+j}{k-j}
$$
and we sum over all values of $j$ (i.e., $0 \leq j \leq \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$ is the same as $0 \leq j \leq k-j$).

Comment: Good idea. Perhaps the summand on the RHS becomes $\binom{m+k-2j-1}{k-2j}$. Then what?

Comment: $\binom{m+k-2j-1}{k-2j} = \dim S^{k-2j} \mathbb{C}^m$ so RHS = dimension of forms in $m$ variables, of degree $\leq k$, of degree same parity as $k$... no idea if that helps.

Comment: I like the approach, Let's hope someone can pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For convenience set $m=n-2k$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \binom{n-2k+j}{j,k-2j,n-3k+2j} &= \binom{m+j}{j,k-2j,m-k+2j} \\
    &= \binom{m+j}{m} \binom{m}{k-2j} \\
    &= [t^j](1-t)^{-(m+1)} \cdot [t^{k-2j}](1+t)^m \\
    &= [t^{2j}](1-t^2)^{-(m+1)} \cdot [t^{k-2j}](1+t)^m
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $[t^a]p$ is the coefficient of $t^a$ in the formal power series $p=p(t)$.
Note that $[t^{2j+1}](1-t^2)^{-(m+1)} = 0$. So the left hand side is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  [t^k](1-t^2)^{-(m+1)}(1+t)^m &= [t^k](1-t)^{-(m+1)}(1+t)^{-1} \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^k [t^{k-j}](1-t)^{-(m+1)} \cdot [t^j](1+t)^{-1} \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{m+k-j}{m} (-1)^j \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \binom{m+k-2j}{m} (-1)^{2j} + \binom{m+k-2j-1}{m} (-1)^{2j+1} \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \binom{m+k-2j}{m}-\binom{m+k-2j-1}{m} \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \binom{m+k-2j-1}{m-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Great! It is a cool proof, in the true fashion of *generatingfunctionology*.

Answer (score 9):

As functions of $k$, it appears that both sides satisfy the recurrence
\begin{align}
& 4(-n+2\,k+1) (-n+2k) A(n,k) \\[6pt]
& {} + (8k^2-8\,kn+n^2+10k-9n) A(n,k+1)\\[6pt]
& {} + (k+2)(-n+k) A(n,k+2)=0
\end{align}
with $A(n,0) = 1$, $A(n,1) = n-2$.

Comment: Interesting. Can this be justified?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan It looks like this _might_ be gotten from a suitable extension of Gosper's algorithm / WZ pairs?

Comment: Not in a transparent way, really.